# SELECT several records for each DISTINCT one in a single query

Tags: mysql, join, distinct

I need to select several rows per each distinct record. Pretty much something like asked here [Select first n records for each distinct ID in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364224/select-first-n-records-for-each-distinct-id-in-sql-server-2008), although I use MySQL.

The purpose can be achieved by running 21 queries in this case: 1 general and 20 to get the subrecords, i.e. something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `user_id`
FROM `posts`
WHERE `deleted` = '0'
ORDER BY `user_id` ASC
LIMIT 20
```

... to select all rows needed, and then

```
SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE `deleted` = '0'
AND `user_id` = ?
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

... in a loop per each row selected by the first query.

Basically, I sort of need to get 5 posts of each user. I need this done in a single query. The `posts` setup is just for example, I made this up so it's, hopefully, easier to understand what I need.

I started with the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `posts` 
WHERE `user_id` 
IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` 
    FROM `posts` 
    ORDER BY `user_id` DESC 
    LIMIT 4
) 
LIMIT 5
```

But I get the `#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'` error.

So I've tried the `JOIN` idea like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856430/722036):

```
SELECT  posts.id,
        posts.user_id,
        NULL
FROM    (
        SELECT  posts.user_id
        FROM    posts
        WHERE   posts.deleted = 0
        LIMIT 20
        ) q
JOIN    posts
ON      posts.user_id = q.user_id
```

I've also tried several nested queries as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124492/722036):

```
SELECT *
FROM posts 
WHERE user_id IN (
      SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT user_id 
            FROM posts 
            LIMIT 20
      ) 
      as t);
```

And the other solutions found on the Internet. But they either do not work or just simply select the first N rows from the database (regardless of the conditions and joins for some reason). Tried `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, even `INNER JOIN`, but still no success.

Please help.

**UPDATE** Forgot to mention that the table is around 5GB in size.

**UPDATE** 
Tried the sub-sub query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `posts` 
WHERE
  `user_id` IN ( SELECT `user_id` FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` 
     FROM `posts` 
    ORDER BY `user_id` DESC 
    LIMIT 4 ) limit_users
  ) 
LIMIT 5
```

Same as above, it returns the following:

```
+----+---------+------+
| id | user_id | post |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 |       1 |    a |
+----+---------+------+
|  2 |       1 |    b |
+----+---------+------+
|  3 |       1 |    c |
+----+---------+------+
| .. |      .. |   .. |
```

I.e. the 5 (which is what the outer `LIMIT` is set to) rows for the same user. The weird thing is that if I run the sub and sub-sub query alone:

```
    SELECT `user_id` FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` 
     FROM `posts` 
    ORDER BY `user_id` DESC 
    LIMIT 4 ) limit_users
```

I get the 4 distinct values:

```
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
|       2 |
+---------+
|       3 |
+---------+
|       4 |
+---------+
```

Comment: See the section headed **Select the top N rows from each group** from @BaronSchwartz's article, [How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use variables, doing two different counts on an ordered query: one on the number of the posts for each user, and one for the users:

```
SELECT posts_counts.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    posts.*,
    @post_count:=case when @prec_user_id=user_id then @post_count+1 else 1 end as pc,
    case when @prec_user_id<>user_id then @user_count:=@user_count+1 else @user_count end as uc,
    @prec_user_id:=user_id
  FROM
    posts,
    (select @prec_user_id:=0, @user_count:=0, @post_count:=0) counts
  ORDER BY
    posts.user_id ) posts_counts
WHERE pc<5 and uc<4
```

**EDIT:** You might also consider trying this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `posts` 
WHERE
  `user_id` IN ( SELECT user_id FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` 
     FROM `posts` 
    ORDER BY `user_id` DESC 
    LIMIT 4 ) limit_users
  ) 
LIMIT 5
```

(this will justs select 5 posts, out of all posts from each selected user, so it's still not what you need, but it uses a trick to use a LIMIT in a sub-subquery)

**EDIT2:** Next query will limit 5 posts for each of the 20 users:

```
select posts_limited.*
from (
  select
    posts.*,
    @row:=if(@last_user=posts.user_id, @row+1, 1) as row,
   @last_user:=posts.user_id
  from
    posts inner join
    (select user_id from
      (select distinct user_id
       from posts
       order by user_id desc
       LIMIT 20) limit_users
    ) limit_users
    on posts.user_id = limit_users.user_id,
    (select @last_user:=0, @row:=0) r
  ) posts_limited
  where row<=5
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How is this going to work on a big table? It just loks too complex to me :)

Comment: @TheSexiestManinJamaica it looks complex at first but once you get uses to variables, it should be clear what it does... but on a big table it can be slow... let me think about some other solutions...

Comment: @TheSexiestManinJamaica i'm not sure about one thing... you need to extract 5 posts, from 20 different user?

Comment: @TheSexiestManinJamaica sometimes MySql is weird... while you can't LIMIT a subquery, you can LIMIT a sub-subquery... I don't know how fast it is, but you should give it a try. If this solution works and is fast enough, it's much easier and faster to limit the maximum number of posts for each user

Comment: @ fthiella yes, I need to get 5 posts by each one of 20 different users, 100 posts in total. I believe I've tried the sub-sub query thing, but it looks like yours is quite different from mine, so I'll give it a try.

Comment: @TheSexiestManinJamaica pls see my updated answer, last query will limit to maximum 5 posts for each one of 20 different user. If I have not made any mistake, it should work, but I am not sure if it can be optimized

Comment: Wow, looks good. I will only be able to test it tomorrow, but surely thank you for your time and effort.